# Javascript "Object not a constructor" error when using namespaces?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have the following JS code:

```
window.Foo = {};
window.Foo.Name1 = function()
{
    function Bar1(param1)
    {
        this.Name = param1;

    }

}


var gMyBar = new Foo.Name1.Bar1("hello world");
alert(gMyBar.Name);
```

I'm getting the error "Foo.Name1.Bar1 is not a constructor" in my Firefox error console... what gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're confused about "namespaces" in JavaScript.  JavaScript does not have namespaces, only objects and functions.  You've declared `Bar1` as a local function within the closure of the function `Name1`.  It is not a member of `Name`.  I'm not sure what you're going for here, but I think this is it:

```
var Foo = {
  Name1: {
    Bar1: function(param1) {
      this.Name = param1;
    }
  }
};

var gMyBar = new Foo.Name1.Bar1("hello world");
alert(gMyBar.Name); // hello world
```

Comment: yep that idea is what im going for

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Bar1` is a local function, available only to the scope of the `Name1` function.

If you want to access `Bar1`, you could make `Name1` another *namespace level*:

```
window.Foo = {};
window.Foo.Name1 = {
  Bar1: function (param1) {
    this.Name = param1;
  }
};

var gMyBar = new Foo.Name1.Bar1("hello world");
alert(gMyBar.Name); // "hello world"
```